# PostgreSQL Trimming Leading and Trailing Characters: = and "

Tags: postgresql, csv, talend, data-integration

I'm working to build an import tool that utilizes a quoted CSV file.  However, several of the fields in the CSV file are reported as such:

"=""38000"""

Where **38000** is the data I need.  The data integration software I use (Talend 6.11) already strips the leading and trailing double quotes for me (so, "38000" becomes 38000), but I can't find a way to get rid of those others.

So, essentially, I need "=""38000""" to become "38000"  where the leading "=" is removed and the trailing "" is removed.

Is there a TRIM function that can accomplish this for me?  Perhaps there is a method in Talend that can do this?

Answer (score 2):

As the other answer stated, you could do that operation in SQL. Or, you could do it in Java, Groovy, etc, within Talend.  However, if there is an existing Talend component which does the job, my preference is to use it.  That leads to faster development, potentially less testing, and easier maintenance. Having said that, it is important to review all the components which are available, so you know what's available to you.

You can use the Talend component [tReplace](https://help.talend.com/display/TalendComponentsReferenceGuide61EN/tReplace), to inspect each of the input columns you want to trim of quotes and equal signs. A single tReplace component can do search and replace operations on multiple input columns. If all the of the replaces are related to each other, I would keep them within a single tReplace.  When it gets to the point of doing unrelated replacements, I might place those within a new tReplace so that logical operations are organized and grouped together.

```
tReplace 
 For a given Input Column 
   search for "=", replace with ""
   search for "\"", replace with ""
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like that:

```
SELECT format( '"%s"', trim( both '"=' from '"=""38000"""' ) );

-[ RECORD 1 ]---
format | "38000"
```

1st: trim() function removes all " and = chars. Result is simply 38000 
2nd: with format can add double quote back to get wishful end result

Alternatively, can use regexp and other Postgres string functions.

See more:
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-string.html